# wasm not loaded while using tensorflow in web worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, webassembly, tensorflow.js

I am using @tensorflow/tfjs-tflite in my react app, and they run heavy codes.
In order to prevent blocking UI while executing tf, the function run in a web worker.

However, it occurs the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_malloc')
    at $jscomp.generator.Engine_.program_ (runevm.js:100161)
    at $jscomp.generator.Engine_.nextStep_ (runevm.js:98960)
    at $jscomp.generator.Engine_.next_ (runevm.js:98956)
    at $jscomp.generator.Generator_.next (runevm.js:98961)
    at g (runevm.js:99760)
```

In DevTools, I confirmed that malloc function is defined at a wasm file, and that is not loaded to context. ("tflite_web_api_cc_simd.wasm")

[image: Debug Snapshot]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hey @Intel Min, I'm currently facing with a similar issue, did you solve the problem?